# TLS session and DNSCrypt

Tags: ssl, dns

DNS traffic (requests and responses) has been encrypted by DNSCrypt.  In this case, is hostname (https://www.example.com /destination IP adress) readable in transit by a third party during my TLS session? Actually i would like to clarify what does make hostname visible to others - unencrypted DNS traffic only or both unencrypted DNS and initial request to the destination server in the TLS session context?

Answer (score 0):

The hostname is part of the [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension of the TLS handshake. When this extension is used it is send in clear inside the ClientHello part of the handshake. All current browsers use SNI.

Apart from that the hostname is usually part of the servers certificate. The certificate is also send in clear by the server during the SSL handshake.

Which means DNSCrypt only protects the DNS lookup and nothing more.

BTW, a better forum for such kind of questions is security.stackexchange.com.